# Амбидекстр или амбидекстер?

Tags: орфография

Я — вот, оно самое (одинаково владею обеими руками), но никогда не знаю, как точно пишется это слово. В одних источниках вижу "амбидекстр", в других — "амбидекстер". А как все-таки правильно?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

В орфографическом словаре под ред. Лопатина 2004 года зафиксировано написание *амбидекстр*.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, амбидекстер - разговорное, произносительное, в психологическом словаре - "стр": Амбидекстр - человек, одинаково хорошо владеющий правой и левой руками